# Appfuse 3.5 and DB2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2, appfuse

I am trying to create a webapp using [appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home).  By default appfuse configures the app to work with a MySQL database, however I'd like use a [DB2](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/) database.  Since Appfuse uses hibernate and Spring this should be a fairly straightforward configuration change but I haven't been able to get it to work.  I get the following error on all my SQL calls:

```
create table role (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    description varchar(64),
    name varchar(20),
    primary key (id)
);
HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table role (id bigint generated by default as identity, description varchar(64), name varchar(20), primary key (id))
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;imary key (id));END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=4.19.26
```

Here is how I have configured hibernate and the jdbc connection:

```
<jdbc.groupId>com.ibm.db2</jdbc.groupId>
<jdbc.artifactId>db2jcc4</jdbc.artifactId>
<jdbc.version>10.5</jdbc.version>
<jdbc.driverClassName>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</jdbc.driverClassName>
<jdbc.url>jdbc:db2://<IP Address>:<Port>/<DBName>:currentSchema=<schemaName>;</jdbc.url>
<jdbc.username><username></jdbc.username>
<jdbc.password><password></jdbc.password>
<jdbc.validationQuery><![CDATA[SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;]]></jdbc.validationQuery>

<hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</hibernate.dialect>
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong.  I can use the same db2jcc4.jar and connection parameters to connect to the DB through netbeans and copy and paste the sql from above and it executes without error.  So I don't believe it's a syntax error as the SQLCODE=104, SQLSTATE42601 indicates. I'm at a loss of what I'm doing wrong.  Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `create table role` statement issued by Hibernate has syntax that's not valid for DB2. I guess the Hibernate dialect does not switch from MySQL to DB2 somehow. Or may be the application issues SQL statements directly.

Comment: However, I executed the create table statement and it is valid. :S

Comment: What version of DB2 are you connecting to, and what platform is it running on?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  The version of DB2 is v10.5.0.5 and it's running as an IBM bluemix service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer but it worked:  I removed the validation Query.

If anyone knows of a better answer or why this worked please share.

Thank you!